# Php Pulling Exactly Nothing from DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
#Show Recent Comments
$rows2 = array();
if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                    
    while($row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows2[] = $row2;
    }
}
$rows22 = array();
if ($sth22->rowCount()) {                                    
    while($row22 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows22[] = $row22;
    }
}   


$theCommentID = $row['CommID'];
echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>";
echo "<div class='comment'>by <em>{$row22['uname']}</em> on {$row2['date']} about <code><a href='course.php?cID={$row2['cID']}'>{$row2['prefix']} {$row2['code']}</a>&nbsp;</code>  during  {$row2['Qtr']},  {$row2['Yr']} <span style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'><img src='img/report.png' /> <a class='report' href='report.php?commID={$row2['CommID']}'>Report</a></span><br />{$row2['info']} </div>";


// Get any professor comments currently present ON LOAD
$pID2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $u, $p);
$pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
        SELECT C.cID, Co.CommID, prefix, code, info, date, Qtr, Yr
        FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
        WHERE P.pID = ?
        AND C.cID = Co.CName AND P.pID = Co.pID 
        ORDER BY Yr DESC;
');

$sth2->execute(array( $pID2 ));

// Get the user of the comment
$pID22 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$pdo22 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $u, $p);
$pdo22->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth22 = $pdo22->prepare("
        SELECT uname FROM Student S, Comment C WHERE S.usrID = C.usrID and commID='$commentId';
");

$sth22->execute(array( $pID22 ));
```

Is something wrong with my arrays I'm creating? They are not yielding any results upon executing query.

Comment: Seriously. Please stop chucking walls of code at us. Make [testcases](http://sscce.org/) (which is a similar process to debugging, which would be polite of you to try before resorting to asking here), and _read the manual_ (you indicated elsewhere that you don't believe in it). I shan't be responding again until you do.

Answer (score 3):

Well... you're assigning values first, executing queries later. It's like locking your door first, and then trying to exit your home. You can't expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mchl's answer:

```
$rows22 = array();
if ($sth22->rowCount()) {                                    
    while($row22 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows22[] = $row22;
    }
}
```

Did you mean:

```
$rows22 = array();
if ($sth22->rowCount()) {                                    
    while($row22 = $sth22->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // $sth22 here
        $rows22[] = $row22;
    }
}
```

And let this be a lesson to you that this style of code — and *certainly* your choice of variables — is incredibly error-prone.